# Instrumantation causes corruption of constant pool

Tags: java, instrumentation

I have a method A.passLong(Long) that receives a long as a parameter. I instrument class B, and add an invocation of that method, and pass a long constant.

When I debug the invoked method  A.passLong(Long) I see that the method receives a number which is not the number I passed as a parameter.

I used "javap -verbose" to decompile a dump of the class with the instrumented code, and it looks like the number read from the constant pool (the number I see with the debugger) is a concatenation of the expected number and the following number in the constant pool.

It is not a JIT issue since it reproduces when debugging and JIT is disabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: Fix the instrumentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a [known issue](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6394084) in Sun Java1.5_04. They have since added a some code to guard reflection (and constant pool) in classes while they get redefined. See [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/releasenotes-142123.html). I know Sun's 1.5_12 works well.

Which JVM are you using, then?

Comment: I was using jdk150_06. I switched to jdk1.5.0_12, and that solved it. Thanks